# Scala self type alias name overriding fields issue

Tags: scala, akka, self-type, cake-pattern

I've encountered a problem when self type alias name 'overrides' extended class field and compiler doesn't indicate it.

My scenario with akka actors:

```
class MyActor extends Actor { self: SomeModuleInjection =>
  ...
  someActorRef ! SomeMessage
  ...
}
```

In case I use `self` alias name. I send message from `MyActor` to other actor, the sender becomes `deadLetters`. When I use different alias instead of `self` it works fine.

I suppose `!` method implicitly must take self field of Actor class, but it's being hidden by the `self` alias.

In my opinion it's dangerous to use self type alias name if you extend a class.

My question: Why compiler doesn't tell about duplicated alias/field names? Or how to handle this problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong according the type system, even if that's not what you want to do in your specific case

Comment: How to handle the problem? Use an alias other than `self`.

Comment: I also wouldn't say it's _overriding_, it's _shadowing_, which the compiler often will not produce warnings for.

Comment: It's no different from having a local variable called `self`.